# ruby adding to hash with array value

Tags: ruby, hash

I tried the following ruby code, which I thought would return a hash of word lengths to the words with those lengths. Instead it is empty.

```
map = Hash.new(Array.new)    
strings = ["abc","def","four","five"]
strings.each do |word|
  map[word.length] << word  
end
```

However, if I modify it to

```
map = Hash.new
strings = ["abc","def","four","five"]
strings.each do |word|
  map[word.length] ||= []
  map[word.length] << word  
end
```

It does work.

Doesn't the first version just create a hash whose default values are an empty array? In this case, I don't understand why the 2 blocks give different values.

Comment: This is strange. For the first example, it works if you do `map = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't actually assigning anything to the hash keys, you're just using the `<<` operator to modify the existing contents of a default value. Since you don't assign anything to the hash key, it is not added. In fact, you'll notice the default value is the one modified:

```
h = Hash.new []
p h[0]           # []
h[0] << "Hello"
p h              # {}
p h[0]           # ["Hello"]
p h[1]           # ["Hello"]
```

This is because the same `Array` object is maintained as the default value. You can fix it by using the `+` operator, though it may be less efficient:

```
map = Hash.new []
strings = ["abc", "def", "four", "five"]

strings.each do |word|
    map[word.length] += [word]
end
```

And now it works as expected.

Comment: Helped me a lot, thanks! This didn't work for me however until i changed the `word` after `+=` to be an array, like `[word]`

Answer (score 12):

All being said, check [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
["abc", "def", "four", "five"].group_by(&:length)
#=> {3=>["abc", "def"], 4=>["four", "five"]}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning ruby so learning the idioms is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think what the first version really means is that the default value is only *one* array. The second example explicitly creates a new array if one doesn't exist yet.

This looks like a good read to further [clarify](http://blog.luckyus.net/2008/11/13/a-hash-of-arrays-and-a-hash-of-hashes-in-ruby/).